# Angular 10 - Chained Promises on Array Don't Calculate All Properties

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, promise, angular10

I'm new to Angular and TypeScript, and have encountered a problem:
I have an array of objects of type `LabObject` model: my LabObject model has quite a lot of properties, along with two private properties that are calculated (`private _labTest: number` and `private _vitalSign: number`).

I create an array of type LabObject and populate it using a for loop. Naturally, I have noticed that these two calculations don't finish while the loop is still running, because they are quite heavy, so I figured I'd use a promise.
I thought if I ran the loop in the first promise, and then chained two promises after that, one for each calculation, it would force my calculations to finish running before I did anything else with that array.

It seems that I am wrong, as not all array elements wind up with calculated _labTest and _vitalSign, and in some elements either one or both of them are missing.

Here is my method:

```
createFile() {

    let getLabObject = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let lab_objects: LabObject[] = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let lo = this.createLabObject();
        lab_objects.push(lo);
      }
      resolve(lab_objects);
    });

    let getLabTest = objects => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        objects.forEach(item => {
          item.CalculateLabTest();
        });
        resolve(objects);
      });
    };

    let getVitalSign = objects => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        objects.forEach(item => {
          item.CalculateVitalSign();
        });
        resolve(objects);
      });
    };

    let backend = objects => {
      this.http.post('my backend url address', JSON.stringify(objects))
        .subscribe(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
        });
    }

    getLabObject.then(objects => {
      return getLabTest(objects);
    }).then(objects => {
      return getVitalSign(objects);
    }).then(objects => {
      return backend(objects);
    });

  }
```

I get a JSON object that looks something like this:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'name1'},
{id: 2, name: 'name2', _labTest: 10},
{id: 3, name: 'name3', _vitalSign: 17},
{id: 4, name: 'name4', _labTest: 8, _vitalSign: 6}]
```

But I would like for the _labTest and _vitalSign to be calculated for each and every one of the elements.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So are the calcs async..? Also, the http (if Angular http) is not a promise but an observable. I don’t think you need to bother with promises at all..

Comment: @MikeOne, Each of the calcs are quite simple: a sum of some properties of my model or sum of method results in my model. The only reason I thought to use promises in the first place is because I saw I wasn't getting all properties on all elements. Can you think of another way?

Comment: If those functions are not async, you could just call them sequentially and after that call the http observable and subscribe to it..

Comment: @MikeOne Even if they take a lot of time to complete? Will my code wait for me? :)

Comment: I’d need to see createLabObject to see what it does. Backend is async at least.. but that is okay at it seems to be your last action..

Comment: @MikeOne, thank you sooo much for your help. I wound up finding my mistake elsewhere in the code - I was passing incorrect data types to my LabObject constructor and it made a mess everywhere else. However, you just taught me a valuable lesson about promises being for async methods and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need promises for this. Actually the asynchronous code is probably the cause of the incomplete objects.

What you are looking for is a [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). This lets you access a method that calculate a value as-if it is a property. So it is always correct and easy to access. Add a function to extract an object from your `LabObject` and you are ready to submit it to your backend.

Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fwnzxy)

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  labtest: LabObject[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.labtest.push( new LabObject( 2, 8 ) );
    this.labtest.push( new LabObject( 2, 5 ) );
    this.labtest.push( new LabObject( 34, 1 ) );
    this.labtest.push( new LabObject( 10, 1 ) );
  }
  log() {
    const json = this.labtest.map( labtest => labtest.as_object() );
    console.log( JSON.stringify(json) );
    // instead of logging you want to submit the JSON to your backend to do whatever you wanted to do...
  }
}

class LabObject {
  constructor( 
    public type_a_test: number, 
    public type_b_test: number 
  ) {}

  private get _labTests(): number {
    return this.type_a_test + this.type_b_test;
  }
  private get _vitalSign(): number {
    return 2;
  }
  public as_object(): object {
    return {
      labtests: this._labTests, 
      vitalsigns: this._vitalSign
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rob, I found my error elsewhere in the code (incorrect data types), but your answer also helped improve my code and make it look just a touch more professional :)